# Как сохранять настройки записи в WP в шаблон?

Tags: wordpress

Итак, например есть статья с категорией "А" + мета-теги "Б", "С", и т.д.
Возможно ли сделать так чтобы я не выбирал категорию и мета-теги, а это уже сразу настраивалось благодаря шаблону записи или спец. типом записи?

Comment: Нет, нельзя. Вот об иерархии шаблонов WordPress: https://wp-kama.ru/id_7654/ierarhiya-fajlov-temy-shablona.html

Comment: Можно ли тогда хоть как то это автоматизировать?

Comment: Конечно. Писать код в шаблоне, если вы не путаете термины. Шаблон - это часть темы, один файл .php. Иерархия шаблонов обсуждается по ссылке выше.

Comment: Спасибо, но как через php взаимодействовать с категориями(не показывать, а отмечать)?